# Squeaky trainers with leather tongue

Tags: shoes

I have a pair of Adidas trainers that I love.
The problem is that when walking, the leather tongue behind the laces can rub against the inside sides of the shoe and makes an awkward squeaking sound (as if the shoes were soaked or sweaty).

Is there anything I could do to stop this sound from being made while walking around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put a piece of duct tape or masking tape on the inside of the top of the shoe, where the shoe's tongue rubs. Put one piece of tape on each side of the laces, of course. Then the tongue would be rubbing against the tape rather than the inside of the shoe. And the tape wouldn't show, since it's on the inside of the shoe.

[image]

I'm not sure what kind of tape would work best for this. The tape has to be strongly adhesive, but the non-stick side has to be somewhat slippery. Use your best judgment, I guess!

Also, over time the heat of your foot may cause the tape's adhesive to become less tacky, and the tape might slide, so you may need to replace it every so often.

Comment: This is a great answer. Easy to do and pretty much free if you have the stuff at home to do it already. Awesome!

Comment: Duct tape!!!!!!

Comment: @djsmiley2k Duct tape fixes EVERYTHING! We just keep proving it, over and over and over ...

Comment: @djsmiley2k Duct tape is like *the force*: it has a light side, a dark side; and it binds the universe together.

Answer (score 2):

[Neatsfoot oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neatsfoot_oil) is a standard leather conditioner that should help; you might also try a *very* small amount of silicone oil -- being careful to avoid seams (the oil dissolves glue) and the sole (which would become slippery).

Answer (score 2):

WD40 will soften the leather and stop it from squeaking. Just rub it onto the tongue and areas in contact with the tongue with a cloth.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of duct tape use sticky back loop side velcro, sticks perfect and stops squeak instantly.use on both sides of the tongue. Job done.
Done this on my very squeaky gazelles and they're perfect now.